# Using Python websockets to receive latest message

Tags: python, websocket

I'm looking to implement something similar to the `on_message` functionality WebSocketApp but using the websockets library, i.e. always read the latest message. However it looks like they only offer `recv()` in order to read the next message in the queue.

My temporary work around is to run `ws.recv()` in a while loop, but I'm not sure whether this is the right approach:

```py
async with websockets.connect(self.socket) as ws:
    while True:
        msg = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=3)
        self.on_msg(msg)
```

With this approach I have two concerns:

1. I'm subscribed to a very high-frequency channel, so I'm concerned `recv` will fall behind in reading the messages in the queue. (I previously had a 0.1s delay in the while loop and noticed that the message I was getting was not the latest. Even after terminating my internet connection, it kept reading from the message queue before raising a connection closed error)
2. I'm currently using a timeout to detect if a message hangs for unforeseen reasons, but there are cases where there are simply no messages and it raises a timeout error. I'm not able to differentiate the two using the current method.

What's the best way to always get the latest message, even if there's a queue of unread messages? Also, how would you do error handling to avoid the issue in 2)?